# Unable to run Grails from command prompt - getting error

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : `D:/ESSENTIAL`

Error occurred during initialization of VM

agent library failed to init: instrument
```

**SYSTEM VARIABLE**

```
JAVA_HOME =C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0
GRAILS_HOME=D:\ESSENTIAL SOFTWERE\grails-2.2.0\grails-2.2.0

path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;D:\ESSENTIAL SOFTWERE\grails-2.2.0\grails-2.2.0\bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GRAILS_HOME=D:\ESSENTIAL SOFTWERE\grails-2.2.0\grails-2.2.0........ i have found solution of this problem and ....and the space in folder name means in ESSENTIAL SOFTWERE is casing error for me... i have renamed the folder to essentialsoftwere without any space and i was able to run grails from comman promt

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the JDK installed to a path without spaces. Try to reinstall to e.g. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0`.

Comment: thanx bro but this was not the problem actually the probleM was the space in
GRAILS_HOME path between the  "ESSENTIAL AND SOFTWERE"